# How do I set the background color for links?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out on how to set the current page I'm at to a different background color than the other links, but to no avail.

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/blog">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I want is to set the current active link to black, and the other four links to grey. That way if I visit *Portfolio*, for example, that link is black and the rest are grey. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully, there is no Javascript involved. HTML and CSS will work fine for this task. First off, let's create your HTML. You obviously know what page you are on, so we are going to add a class to the current page's link. So, for example, if we were on `/index.php/home` our markup might look similar to this.

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="current" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/blog">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, before we color the *current* link we are going to color the rest of the links. We can select the rest of the links via CSS like so.

```
#navigation a {
}
```

The following CSS will select all `<a>` elements that are children of the `navigation` element. So now we need to set its background color. The CSS property for setting the background color is `background-color: xxx`. Where `xxx` is either the hex code, rgb value, or the name of the color. So we would do the following to have all the links grey.

```
#navigation a {
    background-color: #333; /* or whatever grey you want. */
}
```

This will set every link to the color grey. Now, we need to set the *current* link to the color black.

If you noticed, we added `class="current"` to the current link, the *home* link in this case. Next we need to create the appropriate styling for this. Our CSS declaration will look similar to this.

```
#navigation .current {
}
```

The above declaration applies to all elements with the class `current` that is a child of the element `navigation`. And so now we set the background color like so.

```
#navigation .current {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

So, our final CSS would look like so.

```
#navigation a {
    background-color: #333;
}

#navigation .current {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Note that the **order is important!** If we were to put the second declaration first, it would be overridden by the, more general, link declaration.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer with the steps explanation!

I've created the CSS based on this, but however, when I'm on the other link (lets say, Portfolio), the background didn't change. All the links stayed grey.

Comment: @user1433571 Could you post your code on a website such as [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? That way we can see what your code looks like.

Comment: Is this the code that you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/QHMSa/11/
btw, any idea how to set the box above 'Home' to be dark as well?

Comment: Found out how to set the box above the box similar as the current background-color, I just edited the padding of the .current bigger than <a>.

Comment: Ah, yes. Another good idea is to change `display: block;` on `<a>`. That way it takes up as much space as `li`.

Comment: Any idea how to set the background-color if I'm on another link?
Updated version of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/QHMSa/20/

Comment: @user1433571 Just change the background color. [Like so.](http://jsfiddle.net/QHMSa/21/). Also, if somebody helped you you should upvote them and accept their answer.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't done so. Quite new here. I accepted the answer, but I can't seem to upvote because I don't have enough reputation. I don't think you quite understood what I meant. Currently I'm on Home, hence the background is darker. I want when I'm on Portfolio instead, the background becomes darker, while Home, and the rest lighter (grey).

Comment: @user1433571 You know what page you are on. So just use PHP to mark the current page's link with `class="current"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, you can use PHP and CSS, this is better, because this is client independent.
Second option is to use Javascript and CSS

**PHP & CSS**
I prefer this way!
You need to check on every site if the current page is equal to each menu link. Here are some snippets of my solution. It works fine for my site.
I don't know if its working with your way for linking: `index.php/home`. Think you have to adapt it. Because I use real files like home.php and blog.php

this is the menu.php, I include it into every site:

```
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="innertube">
        <ul>
<?
markIfCurrent("Willkommen", "willkommen");
markIfCurrent("Salzgrotte", "salzgrotte-am-fehn");
markIfCurrent("Heilwirkung", "heilwirkung-des-salzes");
markIfCurrent("Farbtherapie", "farblichttherapie");
markIfCurrent("Salzshop", "salzshop");
markIfCurrent("Erfahrungs-<br/>berichte", "erfahrungsberichte");
markIfCurrent("Fragen und Antworten", "fragen-und-antworten");
markIfCurrent("Preise", "preise");
markIfCurrent("Galerie", "galerie");
markIfCurrent("Presse", "presse");
markIfCurrent("Praxis", "praxis");
markIfCurrent("Anfahrt", "anfahrt");
?>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now the php functions:

```
/* filter selected menu items */
function markIfCurrent ($name, $link) {
    $should_mark = isCurrent($link);
    if ($should_mark) {
        $first = strtoupper(substr($name, 0, 1));
        $rest = substr($name, 1);
        echo "<li><span class='current'>".$name."</span></li>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<li><a class='lower' href='".$link."'>".$name."</a></li>\n";
    }
}

/* check if $pageis current page */
function isCurrent ($page) {
    /* reverse mapping */
    if ($page == "willkommen") {
        $page = "index";
    }
    $isCurrent = $page.".php" == getCurrentPage();
    return $isCurrent;
}

function getCurrentPage() {
    $path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $a = explode("/", $path);
    $site_name = $a[sizeof($a)-1];
    return $site_name; 
}
```

At least the CSS:

```
li span.current a {
    background-color: black; /* or #000000 */
}
li span a {
    background-color: gray; /* or #cccccc*/
}
```

---

**JavaScript & CSS**
This is more pseude code, but its the same logic for the PHP version

In this case you also need to check the current url
with `window.location.pathname` you get the url / pathname. split on the slash and extract the file.
Then you can iterate through the elements of your navigation with jQuery like `$("#navigation").find("a")` and then you can set the css style for the a element `a.css("background-color", "black")`